# System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.'

Tags: c#, blazor

I have two of these methods that enables me to read and write my JSON translations files

```cs
        public string ReadTranslateFile(string translationFilePath)
        {
            string json;
            using (var stream = File.Open(translationFilePath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new(stream))
                {
                    json = sr.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            return json;     
        }

        public void WriteTranslateFile(string filePath, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> translationObject)
        {
            using (var stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = new(stream))
                {
                    var t = JsonSerializer.Serialize(translationObject);
                    sw.Write(t);
                    sw.Flush();
                }            
            }
        }
```

This is a little example of how the translate file is structured.

```json
{
    "Organization":
    {
        "Id":"identificaci\u00F3n",
        "Name":"nombre",
        "Parent Id":"Id. de padre",
        "Description":"descripci\u00F3n",
        "Teams":"Equipos"
    }
}
```

I thought when i would use the 'using' statement it would dispose itself upon completion. It happens on both methods depending on the file action (Read or Write).

I tried using `GC.Collect()` But it does not fix the issue, it only prevents it from happening more often...

Now the thing is, It only happens when i delete the file completely and i needs to rebuild the structure.

These are the steps:

1. Gets its Enums from the dll via reflection.
2. Maps them into type of Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,string>>.
3. I send a POST request to the Azure Translation API.
4. I get a response back for the language i asked for.
5. Match the keys in the dictionary and adds a value to it (the translation)
6. Write every KeyValuePair from the first dictionary into the file in other words it writes the translations per key of the first dictionary of the type.

On step 6 that is where it goes wrong at the `WriteTranslateFile` method and throws me the exception: `System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.'`

This happens quite fast is there a possibility it catches up its own stream. When it wants to read/write the second keyvaluepair.

Because when it happens the file looks somewhat translated, but not completed so some fields will still have empty *Values*.

Do i need to make this method async ?

EDIT:

The above methods are used in these methods:

```cs
public void EditTranslateFile(LanguageEnum language, FileActionEnum action, string key, Dictionary<string, string> texts = null)
        {
            GetFilePathForSelectedLanguage(language);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(TranslationFilePath))
                return;

            if (language != previousLanguage)
                languageObject.TranslationStrings = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>(ReadTranslateFile(TranslationFilePath));

            var translation = languageObject.TranslationStrings.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == key).Value;

            switch (action)
            {
                    case FileActionEnum.DeleteEntry:
                    foreach (var text in texts)
                        translation.Remove(text.Key);
                    break;
                case FileActionEnum.NewEntry:
                    foreach (var text in texts)
                        translation.Add(text.Key, text.Value);
                    break;
                case FileActionEnum.EmptyEntry:
                        languageObject.TranslationStrings.Add(key, new Dictionary<string,string>()); //Empty Entry
                    break;
                case FileActionEnum.EditEntry:
                    foreach (var text in texts)
                        translation[text.Key] = text.Value;
                    break;

            }
            WriteTranslateFile(TranslationFilePath,languageObject.TranslationStrings);
            previousLanguage = language;
        } 

        public void InsertKnownDictionaryInTranslateFile(Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,string>> dictionary)
        {
            var translationFiles = Directory.GetFiles(translationsPath).ToList();
            foreach (string translationFile in translationFiles)
            {
                var json = ReadTranslateFile(translationFile);
                json = CheckforEmptyJsonFile(translationFile, json);
                var t = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>(json);
                
                foreach (var e in dictionary)
                {
                    if (!t.ContainsKey(e.Key)) 
                    {
                        t.Add(e.Key, new());
                        foreach (var i in e.Value)
                        {
                            t[e.Key].Add(i.Key, i.Value);
                        }
                    }
                }
                WriteTranslateFile(translationFile, t);
            }   
        }
```

Comment: Consider using locking to ensure that read / write only occurs one at a time.

Comment: It isn't opened in another program?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen it is a serverside blazor app, so no it only happens when i completely get rid of the translation file and not when i add a new entry

Comment: @mjwills Could you provide an example how you would do this in combination with the usings ?

Comment: `ReadTranslateFile(path)` can be replaced by `File.ReadAllText(path)`. `WriteTranslateFile` might still have a purpose, but it's essentially `File.WriteAllText(path, JsonSerializer.Serialize(translationObject))`

Comment: Can you post the piece of code where they are called? Including any .Delete() or .Exists() calls?

Comment: @HenkHolterman I added the methods that uses the write file methods

Comment: A quick and dirty fix is to wrap the methods in a try and catch and do nothing in the catch, The method will keep running untill all values has been filled in.... But this is not a diserable solution

Comment: Not enough context here but your direct problem is most likely your Virus Scanner. See if you can exclude this folder or try a test with the scanner disabled.

Comment: I haven't thought about that, it could be the issue